# pymongo - how to append values to array?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, insert-update, pymongo-3.x

I am trying to create a database if it is not there already in `mongo`, and then create a collection in the database; then insert/update a document (which contains two keys, called `erp` and `dataset` whose value is a list of strings) in the collection. I know how to upsert a document like,

```
self.connection = pymongo.MongoClient(host=db_host, port=db_port)
self.connection.datasets.datasets.update_one({'erp': 'erp1'},
                                             {'$set': {'data_set': ['database1']}},
                                             upsert=True)
```

When the document is inserted into mongo for the 1st time, create a list with string(s) as values for the field 'data_set', but how to maintain/update the list of strings that whenever a new string comes in, just append the existing list for `data_set`.

UPDATE.
The working query

```
connection.erp_datasets.erp_datasets.update_one({'erp_name': 'erp1'},
                                                {'$push': {'data_set': 'database1'}}, upsert=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for a [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) update operator.

> The $push operator appends a specified value to an array.

```
self.connection.datasets.datasets.update_one(
   {'erp': 'erp1'},
   {'$push': {'data_set': 'database1'}}
)
```